# DOJO href - Issue

Tags: javascript, jsp, dojo

I'm using one html page resource in another page like this.

```
<div class="appTrailingAccordionContainer" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionContainer" data-dojo-props="minSize:20, region:'trailing', splitter:true">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionPane" title="Chat" href = "OnlineUsers.jsp">
            </div>
        </div>
```

In a individual page onlineUsers.jsp page works fine, but in this page it gives

```
ReferenceError: ajaxReqForLoadOnlineGrid is not defined
```

ajaxReqForLoadOnlineGrid is a function in the onlineUsers.jsp page. what is the mistake in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's as simple as the error says, the function is not defined. If it works when you visit the page seperately, but doesn't work when you use it through the `href` property, then you probably defined the function on **OnlineUsers.jsp**.

You should know that the `dijit/layout/AccordionPane` module, similar to `dijit/layout/ContentPane`, does not allow scripts to be executed inside the asynchronously loaded page.

So, either move the `ajaxReqForLoadOnlineGrid()` function to the parent JSP page, or use the `dojox/layout/ContentPane` module. This module has a property called `executeScripts` which allows you to execute scripts on the remote page.

Anyhow, the `dijit/layout/AccordionPane` module is deprecated, and moving to either `dijit/layout/ContentPane` or `dojox/layout/ContentPane` is not a bad move.